# typesetting of math exercises

Tags: math-mode, exercises

I am working on creating images / documents developing visual materials and documents aimed at teaching math operations to children with learning disabilities.

Here are handwritten examples I received from teacher:

[image: 500]

[image: 112500]

[image: 193000]

[image: exercise]

Here is my attempt how to do it in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\overset' macro
\usepackage{stix}  % for \lgwhtsquare
\usepackage{icomma} % for comma as decimal separator
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{document}


$500 = 5 \times 10^{\fbox{2}}$
\bigskip

$ 5\overset{\curvearrowright}{0}\overset{\curvearrowright}{0} = 5  \times 10^{2} $
\bigskip

$ 1\overset{\curvearrowright}{1}\overset{\curvearrowright}{2}\overset{\curvearrowright}{5}\overset{\curvearrowright}{0}\overset{\curvearrowright}{0} = 1,125 \times 10^{5} $
\bigskip

$ 193000 = 1,\fbox{9}\fbox{3} \times 10^{\fbox{5}}$
\bigskip



$ \fbox{2}650 = 2,\lgwhtsquare\lgwhtsquare \times 10^{\lgwhtsquare}$
\bigskip

$ 3.857 \times 10^{7} = \lgwhtsquare\lgwhtsquare\lgwhtsquare\lgwhtsquare\lgwhtsquare\lgwhtsquare\lgwhtsquare$
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

However I am not satisfied with result (spacing between digits, empty boxes have not the same size as boxes around digits...) :

[image: latex output]

Is there a better way how to do it?
(Maybe in other free sw?)

Comment: Using a monospace font may help as the width of each character is the same in your examples.